# Kubernetes/Grafana - memory usage does not match in graph

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes UI dashboard shows (this matches the free -m on this minion)

Memory: 7.29 GB / 7.84 GB

This overall memory usage gradually increasing over time. I am trying to get a view into this memory growth using *Kubernetes/Grafana* default dashboard for this metric: memory/usage_bytes_gauge. However, I see the following on the minion

```
 - The units do not match, i.e: approx 7GB used vs 200MiB on the plot
 - Memory change is all over in the graph as opposed to gradual increase
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you plot `memory/working_set_bytes_guage` instead of `memory/usage_bytes_guage`? 
The kube UI might be using working set which correlates with free. 
`memory/usage` includes pages that the kernel can reclaim on demand.

Comment: I tried the ``memory/working_set_bytes_guage`` plot. It is not different in-terms of the graphs, i.e: 300MiB range and nowhere closer to 7.x GB the real number. There has to be a way to correlate the memory (current, historical) to what is displayed through standard tools like **top** for baseline analysis.